# Proof: Pythagorean Triple algorithm is faster by Euclid's Formula?

Tags: c, algorithm, optimization

As a class assignment, I am to write a C program to generate all Pythagorean triples lower than a given value 't'. Here's my code, which first generates a primitive triplet (a, b, c) using [Euclid's Formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_triple#Generating_a_triple), and prints all triplets of the form (ka, kb, kc) for 1 < kc < t.

```
for (i = 2; i < (sqrt(t) + 1); i++)
    for (j = 1; j < i; j++)
        if ((gcd(i,j) == 1) && ((i-j) % 2) && ((i*i + j*j) < t))
        {
            k = 0;
            a = i * i - j * j;
            b = 2 * i * j;
            c = i * i + j * j;

            while ((++k) * c < t)
                printf("(%d, %d, %d)\n", k*a, k*b, k*c);
        }
```

Most other algorithms that I came across use nested loops to check sum of squares, and are significantly slower than this as t grows. Is it possible to deduce a proof that it is indeed faster?

Comment: Yes it is learn about big O notation

Comment: Big-O notation only has to do with *asymptotic* complexity. It doesn't actually tell you what will run faster on any reasonably sized input, as the constant may be wildly different.

Comment: If you want a proof that this code is faster than some other code, it'd be helpful to provide the other code too.

Comment: Incidentally, if you want a faster way to generate all coprime pairs i, j, you should check out Farey sequences.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up on Farey sequences, it's way faster with them! I noticed in my profiler that 70-80% of the time was spent in my recursive gcd(a, b) = {a, b=0; gcd(b,a%b), b != 0} function, while the actual value of gcd was irrelevant. Generating coprime pairs is way smarter, in hindsight and now it's 80-85% faster.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Algorithm complexity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_algorithms) is the general method to analyze algorithmic performance. In particular, [big O](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) is commonly used to compare algorithms based on the worst case situation of each one of them.

In you case you have 4 loops:

- The `for` that iterates thorough `i`
- The `for` that iterates thorough `j`
- The loop inside `gcd`
- The `while` loop

In the worst case each of these loops performs `sqrt(t)` iterations. A big O complexity would be:

```
O(for_i) * O(for_j) * (O(gcd) + O(while))
=
O(sqrt(t)) * O(sqrt(t)) * (O(sqrt(t)) + O(sqrt(t)))
=
O(t*sqrt(t))
```

For the other algorithms that are slower than your method. You can apply a same reasoning to find their big O then show that this big O is greater than yours. For example the naive algorithm that checks all sums of squares will have 2 nested loops; each has at most `t` iterations and therefore the big O is `O(t*t) > O(t*sqrt(t))`.

Comment: Big O gives an upper bound (for the asymptotic growth of a function). Comparing upper bounds is not meaningful, and to compare algorithm run-time, you need to use big theta.

Comment: @Anonymous to my knowledge, when analyzing performance the worst case (big O) is often the interesting one. Analyzing the best case (big Omega) is a good idea like in quick sort: O(n*n) and Omega(n). The average case is also interesting like in quick sort (n log n). Big Theta doesn't always exist, again quick sort! Big Theta is sometimes difficult to compute and is even an open problem for some algorithms like matrix multiplication

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to Euclid's algorithm, if (a, b, c) is a primitive pythagorean triple, so are (a-2b+2c, 2a-b+2c, 2a-2b+3c), (a+2b+2c, 2a+b+2c, 2a+2b+3c) and (-a+2b+2c, -2a+b+2c, -2a+2b+3c). Here's the algorithm in Python (because I just happened to have the algorithm in Python, and I'm too lazy to rewrite it in C, and anyway, it's your homework):

```
def pyth(n):
    def p(a, b, c):
        if n < a + b + c: return []
        return ([[a, b, c]] if a < b else [[b, a, c]]) \
             + p(a-b-b+c+c, a+a-b+c+c, a+a-b-b+c+c+c) \
             + p(a+b+b+c+c, a+a+b+c+c, a+a+b+b+c+c+c) \
             + p(c+c+b+b-a, c+c+b-a-a, c+c+c+b+b-a-a)
    return p(3, 4, 5)
```

Then it is easy to multiply each primitive triangle by successive constants until you reach the limit. I'm not sure if this is faster than Euclid's algorithm, but I'm hopeful that it is because it has no gcd calculations.